# Insert Function in a Hash Table C++

Tags: c++, hashtable

So I am working on the same hash table as before. I've been trying to implement the insert function but it behaves strangely. Take this information and post it in a file for DATAIN:

```
TATUNG CO.EL PR. LONG BEACH CA
KAMERMAN LCIRRUS BEAVERTON, OR
QUADRAM COLOACH AV NORCROSS GE
AST RESEARALTON AV IRVINE   CA
EXPRESS SYREMING SCHAUMBURG IL
DAC SW INCSPRING VAL DALLAS TX
```

This is the code separated into a single stub.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for strcpy()

using namespace std;

typedef char STR10[10+1];
typedef char STR20[20+1];

struct SLOT
{
  STR10 key;
  STR20 data;
};

struct BUCKET
{
  SLOT entry[3];
  int count;
  int overflow;
};

struct HASHTABLE
{
  BUCKET pBkt[20];
  BUCKET oBkt[10];
  int nextFreeOBucket = 0;
};

void InitializeHT (HASHTABLE ht, int MAXPBUCKETS, int MAXOBUCKETS, int MAXSLOTS);
int HashFunction (STR10 key);
void InsertIntoHT (HASHTABLE ht, STR10 &key, STR20 &data);

int main()
{
    int maxP = 20;
    int maxO = 10;
    int maxS = 3;
    HASHTABLE ht;

    STR10 mKey;
    STR20 mData;
    STR10 sKey;

    InitializeHT (ht, maxP, maxO, maxS);

    FILE * inFile;
    inFile = fopen("DATAIN.dat","rb");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        cout << " DATAIN file access error ... \n";
        cout << " Terminating application ... \n ";
        cout << " Press any key ... \n ";
        return -100;
    }
    char crLF;

    while (!feof(inFile))
    {
        fscanf(inFile,"%10c%20c\n",mKey,mData);
        mKey[10] = mData[20] = 0; // add string terminators
        printf(" MyKey: %10s\n MyData: %20s\n",mKey,mData);
        cin.ignore(80,'\n'), cin.get();
        InsertIntoHT (ht, mKey, mData);
    }

    fclose(inFile);

    return 0;
}

void InitializeHT (HASHTABLE ht, int MAXPBUCKETS, int MAXOBUCKETS, int MAXSLOTS)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXPBUCKETS; i++)
    {
        ht.pBkt[i].count = 0;              // set count field to 0
        ht.pBkt[i].overflow = -1;          // set overflow field to -1
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXOBUCKETS; i++)
    {
        ht.oBkt[i].count = 0;              // set count field to 0
        ht.oBkt[i].overflow = -1;          // set overflow field to -1
    }
    // each slot is empty, count and overflow have been initialized
}

int HashFunction (STR10 key)
{
    int iValue = int(key[1]) + int(key[3]) + int(key[5]);
    int hashIndex = iValue % 20;

    return hashIndex;
}

void InsertIntoHT(HASHTABLE ht, STR10 key, STR20 data)
{
    int hashIndex = HashFunction(key);
    int c = ht.pBkt[hashIndex].count;
    int c2 = ht.oBkt[hashIndex].count;
    int c3 = ht.oBkt[ht.nextFreeOBucket].count;

    if (c <= 2)
    {
      strcpy(ht.pBkt[hashIndex].entry[c].key,key);
      strcpy(ht.pBkt[hashIndex].entry[c].data,data);
      cout << ht.pBkt[hashIndex].entry[c].key << " / " << ht.pBkt[hashIndex].entry[c].data << endl;
    }

    else
    {
      if (ht.pBkt[hashIndex].overflow != -1)      // it has an overflow; check the overflow
      {
        hashIndex = ht.pBkt[hashIndex].overflow;  //using the overflow field to navigate through the buckets as hashIndex

        /*strcpy(ht.oBkt[hashIndex].entry[c2].key,key); // this causes the crash
        strcpy(ht.oBkt[hashIndex].entry[c2].data,data);
        c2++;

        cout << ht.oBkt[hashIndex].entry[c2].key << " / " << ht.oBkt[hashIndex].entry[c2].data << endl;*/
      }

      else       // it does not have an overflow
      {
        ht.pBkt[hashIndex].overflow = ht.nextFreeOBucket;
        int c3 = ht.oBkt[ht.nextFreeOBucket].count;

        strcpy(ht.oBkt[ht.nextFreeOBucket].entry[c3].key,key);
        strcpy(ht.oBkt[ht.nextFreeOBucket].entry[c3].data,data);
        c3++;                       // increment the overflow bucket's count
        ht.nextFreeOBucket++;       // allocate the next free overflow bucket
        cout << ht.oBkt[ht.nextFreeOBucket].entry[c3].key << " / " << ht.oBkt[ht.nextFreeOBucket].entry[c3].data << endl;
      }
    } // else/
}
```

The insert function works fine for certain lines. But if I insert ANYTHING into the else if statement past the assignment of the overflow into the hashIndex, the code crashes. I have tried a number of ways and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(ht.oBkt[hashIndex].entry[c2].key,key); // this causes the crash
```

Of course it cause crash, because you have only 10 elements in `oBkt` array, but access it with `hashIndex` which can have values from 0 to 19.

As aside note, why you use C constructs: strings, file access, etc. If you trying to write in C++?

If you used `std::array` instead of native arrays you even probably will get meaningful exception message about why crash happened...

Comment: I was using C constructs because it was getting complicated to use the standard C++ syntax in the insert statements. As a side note, what if I recalculated the hash function in consideration of the overflow bucket array?